# Conditional Expectation as a limit

Tags: probability

Let's imagine I want to compute $\phi(a)$ where $\phi(Y) = E[X|Y]$

Is there an assumption under which the following equality holds? :
$$\phi(a) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{E[X 1_{Y \in [a,a+h]}]}{P(Y \in [a,a+h])}$$

And using Hospital's Theorem another assumption under which :

$$\phi(a) =  \frac{\partial_h E[X 1_{Y \in [a,a+h]}]}{\partial_h P(Y \in [a,a+h])}$$

Comment: If $(X, Y)$ has joint density $f(x, y)$, then the first equality holds as a consequence of the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: Assuming $X\in L^1$ so conditional expectation makes sense, I think you a "$\mathbb{P}$-a.s.".  The centred version $(a-h,a+h)$ is Lebesgue differentiation, and the one-sided limit introduces at worst a null set where it disagrees.  Finally if you want to use L'Hopital's then you are assuming $F_Y$ is differentiable i.e. the r.v. $Y$ is absolutely continuous.